# How to pass test-case forcibly in Async await Node.js Unit Testing code using Chai and mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am using below test-case for testing an service in Mocha and Chai and it is working fine.

```
describe('Google ', () => {
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    const results = await readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
    console.log(`Final Result : ${results.toString()}`);
  });
});
```

There is one scenario which i need to handle with respect to above code. Actually I am getting this exception from service class readGoogle.execute method sometimes.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

And this is expected from readGoogle.execute method perspective. But my requirement is I need to pass the above test case even though I get the error from readGoogle.execute await method.

1) I do not have access to readGoogle.execute method, so I can't handle the undefined check there. Anything to be done in my test case only.

2) I tried to `return true,` in above `'it'` but still, test case is failing.

3) I also tried, assert(true); in above `it`, but still, test case is failing.

Can anyone suggest to me some idea where I could pass the above test_case always (even in success and failure scenario)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you have a test with **readGoogle.execute** invocation like above, and since it is external resource/api it sometimes and up with Exception which is correct behaviour.

In that case I'd suggest to wrap this call in a try-block.

```
describe('Google ', () => {
  it('POST: Google.', async () => {
    try {
        const results = await readGoogle.execute(jmsPayload);
        console.log(`Final Result : ${results.toString()}`);

        //maybe some other assertion here about result object.
    } catch (e) {
        assert.equal(e.name, 'TypeError');     
    }
  });
});
```

Or make some other assertion in catch  to make sure that this is exactly the error you were anticipating.